# Why doesn't my backend update the keywordData column in database

Tags: javascript, node.js, sequelize.js

My idea is to have the ability to add multiple strings at `keyword`, I've been told to use foreign keys and so am I. But I can't figure out why it's not working properly. Any ideas?

My code is as follows

user.js

```js
var User = sequelize.define('user', {
  username: Sequelize.STRING,
  myhash: Sequelize.TEXT,
  mysalt: Sequelize.STRING,
  keyword: Sequelize.STRING
});

var keywordData = sequelize.define('keywordData', {
  keywords: Sequelize.STRING
})

User.hasMany(keywordData)
keywordData.belongsTo(User)
```

User.js

```js
router.post("/newkeyword", function(req, res) {
  keywordData.update(
    {keywordData: req.body.newkeyword},
    {where: {id: req.user['id']}}
  )
})
```

Comment: What is the error are you getting in your console ?

Comment: N/A @aananddham

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to indicate a **foreignKey** option in the second association definition as well as create an auto-increment id for `keywordData` model.

```
var keywordData = sequelize.define('keywordData', {
  id: { type: Sequelize.INTEGER, autoIncrement: true, primaryKey: true, },
  keywords: { Sequelize.STRING }
})
```

Hence, your association should be like this:

```
User.hasMany(keywordData)
keywordData.belongsTo(User, {foreignKey: 'keyword', targetKey: 'keywords' })
```

Also you an refer this [document](https://sequelize.org/master/manual/assocs.html) for more details.

Comment: I get an error when using this code 

`C:\Users\HP\Desktop\passport-sequelize-demo-master\node_modules\sequelize\lib\associations\belongs-to.js:60
    this.targetKeyField = this.target.rawAttributes[this.targetKey].field || this.targetKey;
                                                                    ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'field' of undefined`

Comment: Have you mentioned `field` key any where else ?

Comment: ```passportLocalSequelize.attachToUser(User, {
    usernameField: 'username',
    hashField: 'myhash',
    saltField: 'mysalt',
    keywordField: 'keyword',
});```